# JS array : filter() with map() vs forEach()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Which is more optimized way `.filter() + .map()` OR `.forEach()` ?

Here is a sample array of objects:

```
var personnel = [
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Luke Skywalker",
        pilotingScore: 98,
        shootingScore: 56,
        isForceUser: true,
    },
    {
        id: 82,
        name: "Sabine Wren",
        pilotingScore: 73,
        shootingScore: 99,
        isForceUser: false,
    },
    {
        id: 22,
        name: "Zeb Orellios",
        pilotingScore: 20,
        shootingScore: 59,
        isForceUser: false,
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: "Ezra Bridger",
        pilotingScore: 43,
        shootingScore: 67,
        isForceUser: true,
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Caleb Dume",
        pilotingScore: 71,
        shootingScore: 85,
        isForceUser: true,
    },
];
```

And let say we want to get the final array giving only name and id where `isForceUser=true`

```
[ { id: 5, name: 'Luke Skywalker' }, 
  { id: 15, name: 'Ezra Bridger' }, 
  { id: 11, name: 'Caleb Dume' } ]
```

Now there are 2 ways ti solve it :

1. By using .filter()+.map(), as shown below:

```
var APersonnel = personnel
                    .filter((person) => person.isForceUser)
                    .map((person) => ({ id: person.id, name: person.name }));
```

2. By using .forEach() and pushing a new object:

```
var BPersonnel = [];
personnel.forEach((person) => {
    if (person.isForceUser) {
        BPersonnel.push({ id: person.id, name: person.name });
    }
});
```

Which one of the solutions defined above is better and why?

Comment: Semantically, I prefer filter+map since you want to filter the elements of the array and map them to something else. In terms of performance I don't know.

Comment: Do you have performance problems? Did you identify this code to be the bottleneck? Don't even bother if you did not answer both those questions with "yes".

Comment: What about reduce?

Comment: @arieljuod I wanted the answer in both the perspective: performance and ease/standard. Thanks for sharing your perspective.

Comment: @str I want to know both performance wise and standard wise.

Comment: @Neil I am not comparing individual functions and reduce is not going to give me the desired result. Have a look at the example provided in  the question

Comment: @VarunSukheja The only way to know the performance is to measure it in different browsers and/or Node.js. This is highly implementation-dependant and mostly just [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) on your side. Use the code that is more readable.

Comment: @VarunSukheja you can match an expression and return an array using reduce. Just a note 

Comment: You can  for a lodash function to be added [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5300)

Comment: @cambunctious  done

Answer (score 8):

These are not the things you should seek performance improvements in. You are talking about 'personnel' here. Which is a fairly limited array set, I imagine. If you are having performance issues, I suggest you use the chrome dev performance tab to see what's causing it.

To answer your question, filter + map is semantically easier for the eye, which again is a personal opinion. Strictly performance wise the `forEach` is faster, where most likely a basic `of for` loop is even faster. But again, these are a few milliseconds we are talking about. Which does not justify the cost of rewriting :)

Another way can be to use `reduce`, less code, and only one loop:

```
const APersonnel = personell.reduce((acc, person) => {
  if (person.isForceUser) {
    acc.push({ id: person.id, name: person.name });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: This is just an example, I wanted to know which is better to use of the 2 when compared to performance and standard. Thanks for the answer, well explained.

Comment: @VarunSukheja I've added some example of using `reduce`, in case you are interested :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @pierreudc I never thought of using reduce in this way.

Comment: Why is `of for` faster than `forEach`? is there a source on this?

Comment: @DrorBar it's actually an assumption, because a `forEach` uses a new function context, as to of for is executed in the same trace

Answer (score 2):

The best way is using `foreach`. Because `map` and `filter` are going to create two arrays. `foreach` doesn't create arrays. So `foreach` is the best one. look at those statements bellow,

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I'm guessing forEach would be better.

In the first scenario, you are looping across 5 items, and then again across 3 items.
In the second scenario you are just looping across 5 items. And the if in the foreach is effectively being done in the filter anyway.

There may be an exception if you're working with an extremely large set of data because you would have both arrays in memory, but for anything short of that, I would recommend forEach